# Two aggregation in a single expression

Tags: qlikview

How to resolve the below expression:

```
sum({<Category={'Internal Ops SLA'}>}(RangeSum(Above(sum(InternalOpsSLA),0,12))/TargetOpsSLA)*Weight)
```

It is giving the error in expression, because of the double sum.

The multiplier Weight value is selected as per the category in the set expression modifier. Is there any other way, apart from variable with ONLY as I need to sum the final results, for the above expression ?

Comment: I don't know why the expression within {} is not coming in the question. The expression within {} is <Category={'Internal Ops SLA'}>

Comment: Its the first time that there are no replies in stackflow. Guess many are in vacation.

Comment: It is hard to help without knowledge of what the data looks like and what your goal looks like. This us just a guess but have you tried summing `TargetOpsSLA` in your expression?  
    `sum(  
        {<  Category= {'Internal OpsSLA'}  >}  
          (  
           RangeSum(Above(sum(InternalOpsSLA),0,12))  /  sum(TargetOpsSLA)  
          )  
        *Weight  
       )`

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is pretty old. Responding to it, thinking that it might help a few.

I faced a similar problem in qlikview, while trying to compute Sum of Averages. With an error message:

```
(Error in expression: Nest Aggregation not allowed)
```

I realized that one work around for this is to use, aggregate functions. Instead of grouping them like:

```
sum(avg(<Dimension_Name>condition))
```

I grouped them as:

```
Sum(Aggr(Avg(condition), Dimension_Name))
```

and this worked well for me.

So for your problem, I would try something like this:

```
sum(aggr(if(Category = {'Internal Ops SLA'},(RangeSum(Above(sum(InternalOpsSLA),0,12))/TargetOpsSLA)*Weight),'Dimension Name'))
```